# Facebook deferred deeplinking not working in Android

Tags: android, deep-linking, deferred

I have implemented facebook deferred deeplinking to get campaign information when user install the app from playstore

```
AppLinkData.fetchDeferredAppLinkData(this,
            new AppLinkData.CompletionHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onDeferredAppLinkDataFetched(AppLinkData appLinkData) {
                    // Process app link data
                    if (appLinkData != null) {
                        readCampaignInfoFromFacebook(appLinkData.getTargetUri(), true);
                    } else {
                        Uri targetUrl = AppLinks.getTargetUrlFromInboundIntent(activity, getIntent());
                        if (targetUrl != null)
                            readCampaignInfoFromFacebook(targetUrl, false);
                    }
                }
            }
    );
```

but iam always getting applinkData **null** , Is this issue has been resolved in the latest facebook sdk or still there because iam not finding any solution for it, have tried everthing from facebook docs.

Comment: It was working fine for me till yesterday and suddenly it stops working, any clue what could be wrong from my side?